# Why the characters never rotate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Animators")]
    public Animator[] animators;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Movement Settings")]
    public Transform target;
    public float movingSpeed = 1f;
    public bool slowDown = false;
    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Rotation Settings")]
    public float rotationSpeed;

    private bool endRotation = false;
    private Vector3 targetCenter;
    private bool startWaitingAnim = true;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        targetCenter = target.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", movingSpeed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);
        animators[2].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(animators[2].transform.position, targetCenter, 0);

        if (slowDown)
        {
            if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
            {
                float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 10) / 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 5f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                //animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
                animators[i].SetBool("Idle", true);

                if (startWaitingAnim == true)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(WaitForAnimation());
                    startWaitingAnim = false;
                }
            }

            if (waitinganimation == true)
            {
                RotateAll(new Quaternion(0, -90, 0, 0),
                    Vector3.down, "Magic Pack", animators[2]);
            }

            RotateAll(new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0),
                    Vector3.up, "Rifle Aiming Idle",  animators[0]);

            RotateAll(new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0),
                    Vector3.down, "Rifle Aiming Idle", animators[1]);
        }
    }

    private void ApplyRotation(Quaternion goalRotation,
         Vector3 axis, string AnimationName, Animator anim)
    {
        if (!endRotation)
        {
            float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                    goalRotation,
                    anim.transform.localRotation);
            float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, 100 * Time.deltaTime);

            anim.transform.Rotate(axis, angleThisFrame);

            endRotation = Mathf.Approximately(angleThisFrame, angleToGoal);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool(AnimationName, true);
        }
    }

    void RotateAll(Quaternion rotation,
        Vector3 axis,
        string AnimationName, params Animator[] anims)
    {
        foreach (var anim in anims)
            ApplyRotation(rotation, axis, AnimationName, anim); // However you want to actually apply the rotation
    }

    bool waitinganimation = false;
    IEnumerator WaitForAnimation()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        waitinganimation = true;
    }
}
```

The first problem is that none of the animators is rotating.
No errors or exceptions it's just not rotating.

And I checked with  breakpoint it's getting inside:

```
if (!endRotation)
```

And then it's getting to the else and play the animation/s
Playing the animations is fine but it's not making the rotation/s before.

The idea is that each animator in animators will rotate to another axis/angle/direction. At the same time or depending on other conditions like animators[2] that should wait first for waitinganimation to be true.

Another problem is with the two lines of animators[0] and [1]:

```
RotateAll(new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0),
                        Vector3.up, "Rifle Aiming Idle",  animators[0]);

                RotateAll(new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0),
                        Vector3.down, "Rifle Aiming Idle", animators[1]);
```

Both rotating same angle but not same axis. 
Maybe there is a way to extend the anims params:

```
params Animator[] anims
```

So I will be able to write something like:

```
RotateAll(new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0),
           "Rifle Aiming Idle",  animators[0, Vector3.Up], animators[1, Vector3.Down]);
```

Instead adding a line for each axis change.

Comment: Make sure this is a very basic scene with only one instance of this script, if you have multiple instances of this script it is possible some of those instances are hitting the else case, hence the reason you are getting into the else.

Comment: Don't use the `Quaternion` constructor unless you are extremely familiar with quaternion math. Use `Quaternion.Euler` instead. What happens if you use `Quaternion.Euler(0f,180f,0f)` instead of `new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0)` and `Quaternion.Euler(0f,-90f,0f)` instead of `new Quaternion(0, -90,0,0)`?

Comment: @Ruzihm I will try now.

Comment: @Ruzihm Great thanks it's working using Euler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## When generating `Quaternion`s using Euler angles, use `Quaternion.Euler`.

In general, don't use the `Quaternion` constructor unless you are extremely familiar with quaternion math!

In your particular case, use `Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f)` instead of `new Quaternion(0, 180, 0, 0)` and `Quaternion.Euler(0f, -90f, 0f)` instead of `new Quaternion(0, -90, 0, 0)`